# CSS, background-repeat distance

Tags: css, background-image, background-repeat

I want to set a `background-image` but with an specific distance between the repetitions.

For example, I have this image to become a `background-image`:

[image]

And I want to fix the repetitions in a pattern like this:

[image]

Check the [JSFiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/wgRAM/)

I'm looking for a CSS3 clean solution, not JS, not extra elements, and so forth. If I have to use very modern CSS3 (un-supported) tricks is ok.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess the ship has pretty much sailed, but still there is a solution based on data-URI.

You can generate an SVG containing your image which has a size greater than the image (e.g. to make the margin 60px just make a width equal to the width of the image (40px) + the desired margin (60px) = 100px):

The next step is embedding your image inside of the SVG:

```
<image width="40" height="40" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAFVJREFUeNrs2EENgEAQBMGBoOOsgLQTgaB1dV9Cggf2Ua2g3r2te5xJrvSsjg83mwLnnuYBAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC/tV7+St9L389AgwA9YgGfH7VrXwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
```

And finally add this SVG as a background-image with the data URI:

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="40"><image width="40" height="40" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAFVJREFUeNrs2EENgEAQBMGBoOOsgLQTgaB1dV9Cggf2Ua2g3r2te5xJrvSsjg83mwLnnuYBAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC/tV7+St9L389AgwA9YgGfH7VrXwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" /></svg>');
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

See the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgRAM/3/).

One can say this is quite a big and dirty workaround. However this is a pure CSS solution which does not require creating of additional HTML elements / JavaScript. It has some disadvantages:

1. You need to embed the image with the data-URI. This is probably not the thing you would like to do often.
2. The solution looks a bit heavy.
3. For IE9 you would need to encode the SVG as a URL.

Possible solution to all these problems is using CSS preprocessors, e.g. Sass. You can make a mixin, e.g.:

```
@mixin background-image-spaced($width, $height, $margin-right, $image) {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="#{$width + $margin-right}" height="#{$height}"><image width="#{$width}" height="#{$height}" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,#{$image}" /></svg>');
}

body {
  @include background-image-spaced(40px, 40px, 60px, 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAFVJREFUeNrs2EENgEAQBMGBoOOsgLQTgaB1dV9Cggf2Ua2g3r2te5xJrvSsjg83mwLnnuYBAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC/tV7+St9L389AgwA9YgGfH7VrXwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
}
```

You can add here many things, e.g. all other margin values, you can encode the image to inject it instead of writing it manually using Compass, see e.g. [this article](http://lucidmoon.co.uk/svg/datauri/sass/compass/embedded/svg-data-uri-scss/#encoding) to learn more about this process. This already looks way better and more comfortable to use.

Answer (score 2):

Another belated idea, it may help in cases where gaps aren't too big:

If the total width of the gaps between images doesn't exceed one image width you can use

```
background-repeat: space;
```

[background-repeat on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat#repeat-style)