# Handle space between repeated background image?

Tags: html, css

I have `div` element with size `200 x 200`.

I added a background image to the element to the right side.

```
div {
    background-image: url('./images/dot.png');
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

It is repeating nicely. But I want to control the space between repeated images. I want to add space of `20px` between repeated images. How can I do that?

### Edit

I need to add the space as much as I would like to add. If I use `background-repeat: space` I only get some space but it may not 10px or 20px or 30px. I want to add particular size(specific number).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32580350/1548895).

Suppose we have an apple image:

[image: apple]

#### Step 1. Convert this image to Base64

For example you'll get

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAMDAwMDAwQEBAQFBQUFBQcHBgYHBwsICQgJCAsRCwwLCwwLEQ8SDw4PEg8bFRMTFRsfGhkaHyYiIiYwLTA+PlQBAwMDAwMDBAQEBAUFBQUFBwcGBgcHCwgJCAkICxELDAsLDAsRDxIPDg8SDxsVExMVGx8aGRofJiIiJjAtMD4+VP/CABEIAB4AKAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAaAAACAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAUGBwMJ/9oACAEBAAAAAHF7EAEzEstyjOveEdsam+kw+VE5cxH/xAAXAQEAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAwUG/9oACAECEAAAAMMmE7K3/8QAFwEBAAMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgMEBf/aAAgBAxAAAAC+sMIJc3//xAAsEAACAQIFBAAEBwAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQAGERIhBxMxQQgyUXEUI0JhYoGR/9oACAEBAAE/AFihQhnZdDhVZjpHFJJzxxtH+nAo6twSe1GPZPOmCkM9wegWWSaSOESylNuyPcdFVuddzaEgfQYeiWJP1Ff74xRWqBF02DuIdHJ5P3xHSgsVPJQDUfTd4Jx1Vzla6LMFfarhUSxx0dLEYo18F5Ru3EYqeplytzSw0s0csZPl4l3Bh4dW03A46EZwuOesiGruJMtTQ1r0jTnzKqqHUn+QDaHE2eZE7kixUsTGIoGJYjX0T9jix5/6mSdVaCkatmpWgucb1w3kwyQw8yFm1O8OuPiNgjzFVx5ntU8ImECU9dTAkb1T5JF3eSPBGLLQXK/3OGgp4vzJXA3yHtov7sx9DHTentmQMqUllpUirNjNNPO+4d2aT5mC68D0Mfi3UEKijjFJZTBf4KsFdy1IcnU6nnHUCaW4TR0xSMRRjdt9E4ioxBMrqiBkYEEeiMZau0lZa43mjVnHBP10x//EAB0RAAEEAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAQMSBBFBE1H/2gAIAQIBAT8AdRQeveIwICcfigySC9htsVjZlIdU2/HRzyOT7d1//8QAHxEAAgIDAAIDAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDEQAEEhMhBhQi/9oACAEDAQE/AMg+NI+kmxNteMuoZV5v0cnjMEzx2DyavNVDFDMsZUB669Xg+2IUTyjkD8jH1kZyWom8/9k=
```

#### Step 2: Insert this Base64 to SVG

`'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50" height="40"><image width="40" height="40" xlink:href="[paste it here]" /></svg>');`

#### Step 3: copy this to CSS `background-image`

To get `10px` space we have `50px` width for CSS background-image, `40px` for `image` tag of svg, `50 – 40 = 10 px`.

```css
body {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50" height="40"><image width="40" height="30" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" /></svg>');
}
```

#### Step 4. If need IE/Edge support

IE/Edge has following [bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7157459/):

> This is a longstanding difference between IE/Edge and Webkit based browsers where they do not require almost any values to be escaped in SVG data uris, and we require the entire value after the “utf8,” to be fully escaped. In the mean time, you can easily accomplish this yourself by using javascript’s built in escape function. That value will work in all browsers today.

So to make it work use this SVG as external file or escape `<svg>…</svg>` part in `background-image`. For example using this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/yoksel/details/JDqvs).

---

#### Update

If you want picture align to the right with `40px` space between images and `background-repeat: repeat-y` you need to set SVG height to `70px` (while image height is `30px`). Here is demo:

```css
body {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40" height="70"><image width="40" height="30" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAMDAwMDAwQEBAQFBQUFBQcHBgYHBwsICQgJCAsRCwwLCwwLEQ8SDw4PEg8bFRMTFRsfGhkaHyYiIiYwLTA+PlQBAwMDAwMDBAQEBAUFBQUFBwcGBgcHCwgJCAkICxELDAsLDAsRDxIPDg8SDxsVExMVGx8aGRofJiIiJjAtMD4+VP/CABEIAB4AKAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAaAAACAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAUGBwMJ/9oACAEBAAAAAHF7EAEzEstyjOveEdsam+kw+VE5cxH/xAAXAQEAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAwUG/9oACAECEAAAAMMmE7K3/8QAFwEBAAMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgMEBf/aAAgBAxAAAAC+sMIJc3//xAAsEAACAQIFBAAEBwAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQAGERIhBxMxQQgyUXEUI0JhYoGR/9oACAEBAAE/AFihQhnZdDhVZjpHFJJzxxtH+nAo6twSe1GPZPOmCkM9wegWWSaSOESylNuyPcdFVuddzaEgfQYeiWJP1Ff74xRWqBF02DuIdHJ5P3xHSgsVPJQDUfTd4Jx1Vzla6LMFfarhUSxx0dLEYo18F5Ru3EYqeplytzSw0s0csZPl4l3Bh4dW03A46EZwuOesiGruJMtTQ1r0jTnzKqqHUn+QDaHE2eZE7kixUsTGIoGJYjX0T9jix5/6mSdVaCkatmpWgucb1w3kwyQw8yFm1O8OuPiNgjzFVx5ntU8ImECU9dTAkb1T5JF3eSPBGLLQXK/3OGgp4vzJXA3yHtov7sx9DHTentmQMqUllpUirNjNNPO+4d2aT5mC68D0Mfi3UEKijjFJZTBf4KsFdy1IcnU6nnHUCaW4TR0xSMRRjdt9E4ioxBMrqiBkYEEeiMZau0lZa43mjVnHBP10x//EAB0RAAEEAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAQMSBBFBE1H/2gAIAQIBAT8AdRQeveIwICcfigySC9htsVjZlIdU2/HRzyOT7d1//8QAHxEAAgIDAAIDAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDEQAEEhMhBhQi/9oACAEDAQE/AMg+NI+kmxNteMuoZV5v0cnjMEzx2DyavNVDFDMsZUB669Xg+2IUTyjkD8jH1kZyWom8/9k=" /></svg>');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: right top;
}
```

Comment: It's not working in IE. Why? Please resolve

Comment: @Mr_Perfect Updated my answer.